# RichTextBox Images Issue

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap, richtextbox

I have 2 RichTextBoxes.
All they do is pass values from one, to another.

So if you write something in one textbox, press enter, it passes it to the other.

```
richTextBox1.Text += richTextBox2.Text;
```

When I paste an image and send it to the other textbox, the image is just being replaced by a space.

Any ideas how to handle this?

P.S. I tried both files from the internet, and files from my computer. neither worked. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkHall I was just testing it on WPF. the problem occurs on Winforms.

Comment: See if this [forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/fe9bfcb7-b226-4a54-9882-11c699bf1cb4) article helps, you will need to write some specific code to check for and insert your images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Text` property only handles the text. Try using the `Rtf` property as it should include all the formatting and the images.

Comment: I tried to, but it doesn't write a thing. (I think rather then including the formatting and images, it's thinking everything is rtf code. but not sure about this, just a thought)